# Unicode character in database using hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Can i prevent certain characters being persisted in database using hibernate. For example if i have a class Note which takes note id and note text as 2 properties. Can i prevent characters Unicode characters like FFFE being persistent in database. When ever the user enter characters like FFFE it should replace with AAAA

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to configure  `text` properties to be [accessed by property](http://javaprogrammingtips4u.blogspot.com/2010/04/field-versus-property-access-in.html) . Then in the getter of the `text` properties , replace `FFFE` with  `AAAA` :

```
@Entity
public class Note {

   private Integer id;
   private String text;

   @Id
   public Integer getId(){ }

   public void getText(){
       /**replace() is the function to replace `FFFE` with  `AAAA` ***/
       this.text = replace(inText);
       return  this.text;
   }
}
```

As the `text` properties is accessed by property , hibernate will get value to be persisted in the DB from its getter.